# Extracting a value from a Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

Aim: If the input in text1 matches with a value in superDictionary,then a second dictionary (that corresponds with that value which matched) has it's values multiplied by the number value in num1 WHEN button1 is pressed (a mouthful I know)

e.g. if text1.text = "apple" (which matches with a value in superDictionary) (see in code below), then that match redirects me to appleDictionary whose every entry then becomes multiplied by the number value in num1 (say 5) when button1 is pressed.

The problem: I don't know what syntax to use to do this!

My IBOutlets and IBActions are as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var num1: UITextField!

var superDictionary = ["apple","banana"]

var appleDictionary = ["fibre": 1, "water": 2]

@IBAction func button1(sender: AnyObject) {}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you combine your dictionaries and make a true `superDictionary`:

```
var superDictionary = ["apple": ["fibre": 1, "water": 2], "banana": ["potassium": 2, "water": 2]]
```

Then your button action would be something like this:

```
@IBAction func button1(sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let num = Int(num1.text ?? "") else { return }
    guard let text = text1.text else { return }
    guard var dict = superDictionary[text] else { return }

    for (key, value) in dict {
        dict[key] = value * num
    }

    superDictionary[text] = dict
}
```

---

Notes:

- The first guard statement extracts `num` from the `num1` textField.  If the textField is `nil` the *nil coalescing operator* `??` turns it into an empty `String` which `Int` makes into `nil`.  If there is a string that can successfully be converted to an `Int`, the `guard` statement succeeds and assigns it to `num`, otherwise the function returns.
- The second `guard` statement assigns the string in `text1.text` to `text` or returns if the textField is `nil`.
- The third `guard` statement assigns the proper dictionary to `dict` if it exists, or returns if there is no such dictionary.  This `guard` uses `var` instead of `let` because we will be modifying this dictionary.
- The loop modifies the dictionary by extracting `key/value` pairs and by replacing the `value` with `value * num`.
- The final assignment replaces the dictionary in the `superDictionary` with the modified one.